# Can we send google my business ratings & reviews to service cloud?

Tags: social-studio, social-customer-service

As you know, we can add Google my business page under the social studio.

Does it work in the same way as other social media pages? We can send the case to the service cloud via social automate? The service cloud team can see the review as a case and reply to them accordingly.

Comment: How did you manage to add your Google My Business account in Social Studio ?  This does not seem to be available out-of-the-box : does it require activation ?

Comment: Yes, this is a paid functionality: Purchase the addon by talking to the account rep.One location page is considered one review account.For more info, visit: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_ss_connect_new_google_my_business_account.htm&type=5